# How to hide the parent table cell/row if child is hidden or having no data

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have table (t1) which is binded with some dataset. One of the row of this table is having another table (t2). so t2 is a child of t1. I want to hide row of t1 if there is no data in t2.

I tried setting the visibility expression of t2 as =CountRows() = 0. With this t2 is hidden but there is an empty space created.

I think I have to set the visibility of t1 row which is containing t2. I tried the same expression but it did not work.

Can anybody please tell me how to hide row of t1 if there is no data in t2. Or is there anyway to bind the visibility of t2 with row visibility of t1?

Atul

Answer (score 0):

you can set expression in row visibility property of table (t1) like:

```
IIF(CountRows("Dataset1") > 0,true,false)
```